# R cannot be resolved to a variable when modify xml file?

Tags: android

i create source file : loadanim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc1" android:duration="60" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc2" android:duration="60" />
</animation-list>
```

when i built, R not auto gen. Mess error : R cannot resolve ....
But when i clear `<item>` in file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
//Clear
</animation-list>
```

and built >> class R created.
Now, i can do ?
so bad ...

Comment: Are you using eclipse for that? If yes means, just try this, Project -> Build automatically -> tick. After that just do whatever you want in your xml file. And, just save it. Once clean your project.

Comment: Clean and refresh your project, maybe it will generate..

Comment: @SpK: not work, when i save and not built >> Run, mes error : " Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:...\resources.ap_ does not exist ". when i clean and built >>> R connot resolved ...

Comment: @visheshchandra : try this but it not gen :( 
i should re-install SDK and Eclipse ?

Comment: If you've any errors on your xml files means, the `R.java` will not generated. Check, whether the drawables are there? [Otherwise, show me your workspace like this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W-IlXm_MdzQ/Tr8W0Fcrd3I/AAAAAAAAAHQ/bItPByRaGek/s1600/Eclipse+Workspace.png)

Comment: @SpK : view my project >> [link](http://imageshack.us/f/52/capturecbq.png/)

Comment: In your `.java` files some errors there? Have you cleared out? And, just clean your project once.

Comment: @SpK: view my pro >> [new link](http://nn4.upanh.com/b6.s27.d2/2709898e528224fac79903c5e59eb102_46304784.capture.png
)

Comment: @SpK : .java file error is xxxActivity : setcontentview(R.layout.main) << R cannot ....

Comment: Just restart your eclipse. Otherwise, try to restore your project from local history.

Answer (score 0):

some resource in the application might have some error, check error, by eclipse menu-> windows-> show view-> Error Log and problems, and you can see errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the drawables exist and if you've named them correctly(abc1 etc.,) If yes, then clean the project and rebuild.